# Columns in footer

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to replicate the footer of [this](http://www.timeout.com/newyork/museums) website as part of a school project. 
So far, I've figured out that my divs should be structured like this:

```
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="top-side">...</div>
        <div class="content">...</div>
        <div class="footer">
            <div class="footer-col">
                <h4>Column header</h4>
                <ul>
                    <li>list item1</li>
                    <li>list item2</li>
                </ul>                    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the css I've used is:

```
.wrapper .footer {
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    margin: 5px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: black;
}

.footer .footer-col {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
    width: 20%;
}

.footer .footer-col ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    overflow: hidden;
}



.wrapper .footer .clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

This is my entire code so far. I can't figure out what more should be added to my css for this to work as it was desired meaning, left alignment of every element in each column and **bold** headers for each column. (I've solved this part with `<h4>`)

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replicate the same `footer` of the website you've said, I think a good way to do it is to replicate a similar HTML structure as well.

In that case, inspect the code with the browser inspector and you will se it's 5 groups of heading `h4` + `ul` lists.

[Here's a hint to do it in a JSFiddle I've made.](https://jsfiddle.net/qL9h8s58/5/)

> CSS

```
.container {overflow: hidden; background: #000; color: #fff; }
.footer-tab { float: left; width: 20%; font-family: Arial; }

ul { padding-left: 0; }
ul li { list-style: none; margin: 10px 0; font-size: 12px; }
ul li a { font-weight: bold;  }
```

I didn't make all the code but you can see, I think,  a better structure to achieve it.

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to figure this out with the inspect element option, but since it was a complex website, i had a really hard time figuring anything out.